# Keeping the subview stationary, while superview is moving

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uitableview

I have been trying to build a custom uitableview swipe. I am successful in that. I also wanted to add a uiview as a subview to the tablecell when it encounters touchesMoved. And when i am trying to move the tablecell, I wanted the uiview being appended to be stationary. For that I am also making it move in opp direction (as suggested by one of the answers in StackOverflow). But it is not looking to be stationary. The subview is also moving along with the cell. Please help me find out where i am going wrong? The code is as follows:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self cellForRowAtIndexPath:[self indexPathForRowAtPoint:gestureStartPoint]];
isTouchesMoved=YES;

if ([self supportsSwipingForCellAtPoint:gestureStartPoint])
{

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(highlightTouchedRow) object:nil];

    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGFloat deltaX = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.x - currentPosition.x);
    CGFloat deltaY = fabsf(gestureStartPoint.y - currentPosition.y);
    if (deltaX >= kMinimumGestureLength && deltaY <= kMaximumVariance)
    {
        tempView=[self addnewViewatPoint:touches withEvent:event];
        [cell addSubview:tempView];
        [self setScrollEnabled:NO];
        CGPoint loc = [touch locationInView:self];
        CGPoint prevloc = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
        if(moved==TRUE)
        {
            prevLoc=cell.frame;
            prevLocBack=tempView.frame;
            moved=FALSE;
        }
        CGRect myFrame = cell.frame;
        CGRect backFrame = tempView.frame;
        CGFloat deltaX = loc.x - prevloc.x;
        if(gestureStartPoint.x>currentPosition.x)
        {
            NSLog(@"You have swiped left");
            CGFloat movedDistance=gestureStartPoint.x-currentPosition.x;
            NSLog(@"The movedDistance is %f",movedDistance);
            if(movedDistance<=160)
            {
                myFrame.origin.x += deltaX;
                backFrame.origin.x-=deltaX;
                NSLog(@"The backgroundViewframe position, frameposition is %f and %f",fabsf(backFrame.origin.x),fabsf(myFrame.origin.x));
            }
            [tempView setFrame:backFrame];
            [cell setFrame:myFrame];

        }
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"You have swiped right");
            CGFloat movedDistance=currentPosition.x-gestureStartPoint.x;
            NSLog(@"The movedDistance is %f",movedDistance);
            if(movedDistance<=160)
            {
            myFrame.origin.x += deltaX;
                            backFrame.origin.x-=deltaX;
            }
            [cell setFrame:myFrame];
        }
        if ([swipeDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSwipeCellAtIndexPath:)])
        {
            [swipeDelegate tableView:self didSwipeCellAtIndexPath:[self indexPathForRowAtPoint:gestureStartPoint]];
        }

        [self setIndexOfVisibleBackView:[self indexPathForCell:cell]];
    }

    [self setScrollEnabled:YES];

}
else
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
}


-(UIView *) addnewViewatPoint:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:event
 {

UIView *backgroundView=[[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10.0, 30.0, 200.0, 25.0)] autorelease];
[backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[backgroundView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
backgroundView.tag=101;
return backgroundView;
 }


 - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
   {
if ([self supportsSwipingForCellAtPoint:gestureStartPoint])
{
    TISwipeableTableViewCell * cell = (TISwipeableTableViewCell *)[self cellForRowAtIndexPath:[self indexPathForRowAtPoint:gestureStartPoint]];
    if(isTouchesMoved==NO)
    {
        [self.delegate tableView:self didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[self indexPathForCell:cell]];
        [self touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    if(isTouchesMoved==YES)
    {
        [cell setFrame:prevLoc];
        [tempView setFrame:prevLocBack];
        isTouchesMoved=NO;
    }
    moved=TRUE;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
    //[super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
else
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

}

Comment: There is a lot of code there for someone to read and debug.  Try breaking it down into the parts that really matter.  Try to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not add the uiview that needs to be stationary to the view below the table?

Comment: Thanks a lot...it worked for me... I added 2 views in the UITableview cell and initially made it one view(which is to be stationary) hidden and the other view had its contents. When it encountered touchesbegan, I made the stationary view visible, and moved the frame of the view that contained the contents. It is working really great. Thanks a lot!!!